# Sound latency in HTML5 app on iPad

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I am coding a game in HTML5 + Javascript which uses quite a lot of sounds.  Obviously this is loads of fun given the current state of audio in HTML5.  I am using an audiosprite to minimise loading and delays and it all works fine on the desktop.  All sounds play, no delays.  However, the same code run on an iPad (3rd gen, iOS 6) in mobile Safari is a different matter.  Some sounds playing in sequence are dropped, presumably due to the fact that the previous sound hasn't started playing before the next .play() event occurs.  I don't want to add to timing delays as that will screw up the flow of the game.

Anyone had similar issues and come up with any clever optimisation?

Comment: Mobile Safari doesn't let you play more than one sound at a time. Perhaps that's the reason?

Comment: As far as I understand it, the same thing happens on the desktop.  Each successive .play() event kills the previous sound.  However, on the desktop it seems that the .play() event works faster giving the sound time to finish before the next one comes along.  Not so on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Variable bitrate codecs do cause difference in timing between different platforms. I have noticed some improvement using constant bitrate.